# finding similar values of variable in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I can find similar strings with the following command, but instead of using a string, I need to use a variable to find similar values between two columns.

```
df.filter(df.column_name.like("%Spark%")).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern = "Spark"
df.filter(df.column_name.like("%" + pattern + "%")).show()
```

A perhaps better way is to use `rlike` with a regex pattern to take care of word boundaries:

```
pattern = "Spark"
df.filter(df.column_name.rlike("\\b" + pattern + "\\b")).show()
```